# How do I stop the Aptana javascript autoformatter from putting properties of an object on separate lines?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana

Without turning the autoformatter off altogether, how do I stop the Eclipse Aptana javascript autoformatter from putting properties of an object on separate lines?

It does this:

```
var p = {
    key: 'test'
};
```

And I want this:

`var p = { key: 'test' };`

I checked the settings under Preferences->Aptana->Editors->Javascript->Formatting, but couldn't find a setting to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to format object properties (JSON) to place everything on a single line. If it will be implemented, it makes sense only for objects with a few properties.

-Max